# How to test custom action filter in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I have created a simple action filter in my ASP.NET Core application, this action filter is suppose to log user's activity:

```
public class AuditAttribute : IResultFilter
{
    private readonly IAuditService _audit;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    public AuditAttribute(IAuditService audit, IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _audit = audit;
        _uow = uow;
    }
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        ar model = new Audit
        {
            UserName = context.HttpContext.User,
            //...
        };
        _audit.Add(model);
        _uow.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Now I just wanted to know how can I write unit tests for it. I'm using `xUnit` and `Mock`

Comment: Mock all the necessary dependencies, exercise the method under test and then verify expected behavior against actual behavior

Comment: In the same direction that Nkosi said, I would follow the AAA pattern. Arrange Act Assert

Take a look here on how to test your controllers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, to do unit test, you need to mock the HttpContext as well. 
BTW this bit doesn't seem right: `UserName = context.HttpContext.User` I suppose you meant `UserName = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`. Anyway this is how you test method should look like:

```
 public void OnResultExecuting_Test()
 {
     // Arrange sesction :
     var httpContextWrapper = new Moq<HttpContextBase>();
     var genericIdentity = new GenericIdentity("FakeUser","AuthType");
     var genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(genericIdentity , new string[]{"FakeRole"});
     httpContextWrapper.Setup(o=> o.User).Return(genericPrincipal);
     var controller = new FakeController(); // you can define a fake controller class in your test class (should inherit from MVC Controller class)
     controller.controllerContext = new ControllerContext( httpContextWrapper.Object, new RouteData(), controller );
     var audit = new Moq<IUnitOfWork>();
     var uow = new Moq<IAuditService>();
     // more code here to do assertion on audit
     uow.Setup(o=>o.SaveChanges()).Verifiable();
     var attribute= new AuditAttribute(audit.Object,uow.Object);

     // Act Section:
     attribute.OnActionExecuting( filterContext );

     // Assert Section:
     ... // some assertions
     uow.Verify();

 }
```

Comment: Where did the `filterContext` come from?

Answer (score 5):

The only way I was able to do this was by creating bare-boned concrete classes and testing the HTTPContext result for what I wanted to achieve. Since I was using concrete classes there was no need for `Mock`

The setup:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
   _actionContext = new ActionContext()
   {
      HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(),
      RouteData = new RouteData(),
      ActionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor()
   };
}
```

The test:

```
[Test]
public void Should_deny_request()
{
    // Given
    var resourceExecutingContext = new ResourceExecutingContext(_actionContext, new List<IFilterMetadata>(), new List<IValueProviderFactory>());
    var attribute = new YourAttribute();

    // When
    attribute.OnResourceExecuting(resourceExecutingContext);
    var result = (ContentResult) resourceExecutingContext.Result;

    // Then
    Assert.IsTrue(Equals("403", result.StatusCode.ToString()));
}
```

And this worked for me.

Comment: `new ActionDescriptor()` seems to require parameters, and I can't figure them out no matter what I do.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful for me to test my exception attribute in asp net code!